# Node server started but cannot connect to the IP

Tags: node.js, npm, server

I started the nodejs server but cannot connect as shown here:
[image: Node server not showing index.js message here[![][1]]

In the console it shows running but in browser it is like it cannot connect.
The code of index is as it follows:

```
console.log('Hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii');
var io = require('socket.io');
var dot = require('dotenv').config();
var PORT = 3001;
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var mysql = require('mysql')
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'titan_bidwork',
    password: 'bidwork@123#',
    database: 'titan_bidwork'
})

connection.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log('You are now connected...')
})

http = require('http'),
    server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {  
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Request-Method', '*');
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'OPTIONS, GET');
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
        if (req.method === 'GET') {
            res.writeHead(200, 'Hi, this is a very bad practice.', {
                'Content-Type': 'text/html'
            });
            res.write('<h1>Node Server Running....</h1>');
            res.end('<p>Some random text.</p>');
            return;
        }
    });
io = io.listen(server)
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('subscribe', function(room) {
        console.log('joining room', room);
        socket.join(room);
    });
    socket.on('message', function(msg) {
        console.log('message--->>', msg);
        console.log('msg----=>', msg["room"], msg["message"], msg["flag"]);
        connection.query("INSERT INTO chat_room (room, message, flag) VALUES (?,?,?)", [msg['room'], msg['message'], msg['flag']], function(err, result) {
            if (err) throw console.log(err)
        })

        io.to(msg.room).emit('message', msg);
    });



    socket.on('connect_failed', function(msg) {
        console.log('connection failed', msg);
    });


    socket.on('send message', function(data) {
        console.log('sending room post', data.room);
        // io.to(room_name).emit('chat message', msg);
        socket.broadcast.to(data.room).emit('conversation private post', {
            message: data.message
        });
    });
});

app.post('/getMsgs', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req, '----', res);
})
server.listen(PORT, function() {
    console.log(server.address());
});
```

Comment: Did you try accessing from localhost?

Answer (score 0):

The clue is in the browser error - connection timeout, you only ever appear to send a response back to the client on `GET` requests. However, a lot of the time clients will send introspection requests first e.g. `OPTIONS`/`HEAD`

Try changing your code to

```
server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {  
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Request-Method', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'OPTIONS, GET');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    if (req.method === 'GET') {
        res.writeHead(200, 'Hi, this is a very bad practice.', {
            'Content-Type': 'text/html'
        });
        res.write('<h1>Node Server Running....</h1>');
        res.write('<p>Some random text.</p>');
    }
    return res.end(); // ensure all requests return a response
});
```

FWIW you should checkout [Express](https://expressjs.com/), would make your life easier in terms of targeting specific routes & serving HTML etc.